# Iterate For loop in meteor template

Tags: templates, meteor, iteration

I want to print a 2 dimensional grid based on the x (row) and y (column) ,which obtained from the collection.

I would like to do something like this:

```
{{for i=0; i<=x; i++}}
   <ul class="row-{{i}}">
       {{for c==; c <=y; y++}}
           <li><span class="col-{{y}}">{{num}}</span></li>
           {{num++}}   
       {{/for}}
   </ul> 
{{/for}}
```

The problem the meteor spacebars template doesn't support ***For*** loop as well as variables on the template. The iteration has to be done with *while* and *each* loop.

So how I gonna write the template helper and use it in the template?

```
//example data
var grid = [
                {
                    x:10, 
                    y:20, 
                    title:"first block"
                   .....
                },
                ....
            ];
Template.grid.helpers({
    grid : function(){
               var x = grid[0].x;
               var y = grid[0].y;
               for (i = 1; i <= x; i++){

                   for(c = 1; c <= y; c++){
                   //I don't know how to continue.

                 }          
              }
           }     
});
```

I am new to meteor, and only have experience in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, finally I figured it out. Here are the codes:

```
//example data
var grid = [
                {
                    x:10, 
                    y:20, 
                    title:"first block"
                   .....
                },
                ....
            ];
Template.grid.helpers({
    grid : function(){
               var x = grid[0].x;
               var y = grid[0].y;
               var row = [];
               var num = 1;  // for the increment number
               for (i = 1; i <= x; i++){
                   row[i] = [];//let every row has it own array
                   for(c = 1; c <= y; c++){
                   row[i].push(num);//add the increment number into each row
                   num++;

                 }          
              }
              return row;
           }     
});
```

And in the html template:

```
{{#each row in grid}}
   <ul class="row-{{@index}}">
       {{#each num in row}}
           <li><span class="col-{{num}}">{{num}}</span></li>
       {{/each}}
   </ul> 
{{/each}}
```

Note that the @index is for getting the array index. And it is only works in meteor >= 1.2 version.

Answer (score 1):

With spacebars you can use the `{{#each}}` tag. Here is an example for your case:

```
{{#each rows}}
   <ul class="row-{{rowIndex}}">
       {{#each columns}}
           <li><span class="col-{{columnIndex}}">{{num}}</span></li>
       {{/each}}
   </ul> 
{{/each}}
```

Your data would need to look like this in JSON:

```
{
    rows: [
        {
            rowIndex: 1,
            columns: [
                {
                    columnIndex: 1,
                    num: 100,
                },
                {
                    columnIndex: 2,
                    num: 200,
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            rowIndex: 2,
            columns: [
                {
                    columnIndex: 1,
                    num: 100,
                },
                {
                    columnIndex: 2,
                    num: 200,
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You can see that the JSON object has a `rows` field which is an array. Each `row` has a `rowIndex` and an array of `columns`. Each `column` has a `columnIndex`, etc.

You would need to name a helper like this and return that JSON object:

```
Template.grid.helpers({
    rows: function() {
        return theJSONObject.rows;
    }
});
```

Comment: but the num is the increment number from 1 to 200 (10 x 20).

Comment: @dev-jim you will need to use that nested for loop to build the JSON object and then pass that back from the helper. Spacebars can iterate over data that it is given but cannot programmatically execute. You will need to find a different library if you want that.